# How to declare a function conditionally in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript below, but it seems the if statement is not executed correctly that depends on which statement is put in last, the result will be either n+2 or n*2 while x%2 is always 0:

```
<html>
<script>

var x=10;
while (x<2000) {
if (x%2==0) function collatz(n) {return n+2;}
if (x%2==1) function collatz(n) {return 2*n;}

x=collatz(x);
document.write(x, ",");
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't make function declarations inside statements. Try with a function expression instead, or do the logic inside the function itself.

Comment: You should probably modify `x` with `x++` and just write `collatz(x)`

Comment: Why use functions? Seems like you could just do `x = x%2 ? x*2 : x+2`

Comment: At the very least, you don't need two `if` statements. There are only two possible results.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript language has some unintuitive behavior around function declaration statements: they are actually handled *at the beginning of the containing scope* rather than when they are encountered in execution order.

This is why you can call a function before you've defined it:

```
var x = foo();

function foo() {
    return 1;
}
```

Although you placed your function statements inside the `if` bodies, the instantiate-at-entry rule means that those functions get inserted into the local scope as soon as this program begins executing, with the second one replacing the first due to them being handled in "source text order".

You can use a function expression rather than a function statement to avoid this behavior.

```
var foo;
if (condA) foo = function () { ... };
if (condB) foo = function () { ... };
foo();
```

When a function is defined in this form it is evaluated only when it is encountered, as you intended.

So we can rewrite your program as follows:

```
var x = 10;
var collatz;
while (x<2000) {
    if (x%2==0) collatz = function (n) {return n+2;};
    if (x%2==1) collatz = function (n) {return 2*n;};

    x = collatz(x);
    document.write(x, ",");
}
```

You can see the gory details in step 5 of [Section 10.5 of the EcmaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5).

Answer (score 2):

I think this should help you,

```
<script>
   function collatz(n) {
       if (x%2==0)
         return n+2;
       else if (x%2==1)
         return 2*n;
      }
   var x=10;
   while (x<2000) {
      x=collatz(x);
      document.write(x, ",");
   }

</script>
```

Declare the function outside the loop and you can call the function inside. Also the condition can be put inside the function instead of having two different function definitions depending on a condition.

Comment: Seems like you don't care about code readability (no indentation)

Answer (score 1):

Function declaration are processed in the compilation phase. So the first declaration of collatz is compiled, then the second definition is compiled replacing the first definition, then once compilation is complete the code is executed and the `if`s are processed.

Basically the code is processed like this:

```
var x=10;
function collatz(n) {return n+2;}
function collatz(n) {return 2*n;}

while (x<2000) {
if (x%2==0) {}
if (x%2==1) {}

x=collatz(x);
document.write(x, ",");
}
```

This feature of the language is also known as "hoisting". To avoid hoisting use a function expression:

```
collatz = function() {/*...*/}
```

instead of a function declaration:

```
function collatz() {/*...*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you wanted something like this:

```js
var x=10;
var collatz;

while (x<2000) {
   if (x%2==0) collatz = function(n) {return n+2;} 
   if (x%2==1) collatz = function(n) {return 2*n;} 

   x=collatz(x + 1);
   document.write(x, ",");
  
  
}
```

One of the problems of your code (not the major one) was that starting with 10 both `+ 2` and `* 2` produce only even numbers.

Comment: it would be much better to put `var` before `collatz`

Comment: You should add `var collatz` after `var x=10` otherwise `collatz` will be a global variable.

Comment: Yep. Making the change.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions :

```
if (0) {
   function zero() {
      document.writeln("This is zero.");
   }
}
```

> Note: Some JavaScript engines, not including SpiderMonkey, incorrectly treat any function expression with a name as a function definition. This would lead to zero being defined, even with the always-false if condition.

This is what you are experiencing. Even though the condition of the second `if` statement is never satisfied, because it contains a function definition, that function is still defined for the above reason, on some browsers.

As that same page suggests, as have some of the other answers, the solution is to conditionally assign the function to a variable:

```
var collatz;
if (x%2==0) collatz = function(n) {return n+2;}
if (x%2==1) collatz = function(n) {return 2*n;}
```